# Github Missing Files After a Pod Update (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I am using GitHub to share my project with others.  It was setup and working great.  Then I just did a pod update and pushed with the update.  Now when the project is pulled from the git it seems to be missing pod related files.

In other words, the program builds fine on computer that pushed the update.  However when it's cloned error message like pop up:

> error: <directory location>/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/BoringSSL-GRPC/BoringSSL-GRPC.xcconfig: unable to open file (in
>   target "BoringSSL-GRPC" in project "Pods") (in target
>   'BoringSSL-GRPC')

I tried doing a commit and pushing from terminal but the problem persists.  Then I tried creating a new git but when I push to it all the old commits are still there and the problem persists.  It feels like a fresh clean commit starting from nothing might fix the issue, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your commit changes after pod updated. 
Follow these steps:

1/ Pod update and push this commit to GitHub 
2/ Go to GitHub, click "commits" tab > click the commit that did pod update > see if pods changes is on the file changes record 
3/ If you don't see pods changes, that means you do not push these changes successfully. 
4/ Check `.gitignore` file, make sure it doesn't contain syntax like: `pods/*`

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  The pods did change and I can see the commit message.  As fas as I can tell not every file made it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles on this later, I wasn't able to figure out how to fix the missing file issue so I simply rolled back the project to a git before the pod update.